# Post and wait for return in onclick event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is a list of events I want to perform when the user clicks a link.

- User clicks a link in a search result.
- A session is updated at the server using jQuery post.
- When the session has updated, the search is saved to localStorage.
- When all is done, follow the link that was clicked.

Here's the code:

```
// Manually save the lastest search result and update session at server
$('a.e').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
        $.post("Home/UpdateSession/", $("form").serialize());
        var form = $("#myTable").html();
        localStorage.setItem('myTable', form);
        form = null;
    }
    $.get($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

I get an error saying that the session wasn't updated at the server when I follow the link. And if I put a breakpoint at the action that is called in the post it doesn't break there. Is it possible to do these steps in this order or is the click event called before the post?

Comment: What page are you trying to access? Home/UpdateSession/index.??? or Home/UpdateSession.???

Comment: I'm trying to access the ActionResult `UpdateSession` in the post and then get the href of the link that was clicked.

Comment: So this is .NET that you're working with? Also, try Home/UpdateSession for the url instead of Home/UpdateSession/

Comment: Yes, but I think the problem is in the jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in reply to your comment on Matt Bridges post, to do a ajax call on unload you have to do the ajax call with the `async: false` option like:

```
$(window).bind('unload', function(){
   $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        url: "test.php"
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the async: false was the problem. I posted a full solution to my specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `post()` function happens asynchronously.  You'll need to wait for the post to finish before you save the values to local storage and navigate to the result.  What's happening now is the browser is leaving the page before the post finishes.

The third (optional) argument of `post()` is a callback; you can pass a function that runs when the post finishes.  You need to place all the actions you want to take place after the post in that callback function e.g.

```
if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
    $.post("Home/UpdateSession/", $("form").serialize(), function() {
        var form = $("#myTable").html();
        localStorage.setItem('myTable', form);
        form = null;
        $.get($(this).attr('href'));
    });
    return false; // prevent normal link behavior
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

Edit: added `return false` to prevent normal link behavior

Comment: Hmm, it still doesn't work. If I change the `$('a.e')` to `$(window)` and the `.click` function to `.unload` then it works great. But I want to apply this action to a link click only.

Comment: If I remove the `$.get($(this).attr('href'));` it still performs a redirect. Thought the preventDefault would prevent it?

Comment: See my edit -- add "return false" to the click handler function to prevent the link from being followed by the browser.